# I want to have an Extension method "Equals" between 2 byte arrays

Tags: c#, comparison, binary, arrays, equality

I am doing some byte[] comparisons.

I tried == but this is just like the base Equals, which:

```
byte[] a = {1,2,3};
byte[] b = {1,2,3};
bool equals = a == b; //false
equals = a.Equals(b); //false
```

I tried to add an extension method, but since the overloaded base class' Equals takes the same arguments, it goes to the base method rather to the extension, is there anyway I can use an Equals extension (wthout changing it's name...) or (even better) use == operator?

Here is what I actually have to Compare:

```
public static bool ContentEquals(this byte[] array, byte[] bytes)
{
    if (array == null || bytes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    if( array.Length != bytes.Length) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        if (array[i] != bytes[i]) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Impeccable timing! I was wanting to do just the same this morning and you and Skeet were there with the Q/A :-)

Comment: Linq already has a built-in method called `SequenceEqual` which does exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

byte[] a = {1,2,3}; 
byte[] b = {1,2,3}; 
bool same = a.SequenceEqual(b);
```

Answer (score 8):

You certainly can't do operator overloading with extension methods. The reason it doesn't work for the `Equals` method is that if *any* method is applicable without using extension methods, that method will be chosen before extension methods are even examined.

Even though your `Equals` method is "better" in terms of converting the argument types to the formal parameter types, the compiler always prefers "normal" methods. You'll have to give your method a different name.

However, you can always use the `Enumerable.SequenceEquals` method. I don't believe that short-circuits the length check though (even though it could, for `ICollection<T>` implementations). You could always implement a more efficient version yourself though. Indeed, if you just change your existing array implementation to be called `SequenceEquals` or even `ArrayEquals`, that would be fine:

```
public static bool ArrayEquals(this byte[] array, byte[] bytes)
{
    // I'd personally use braces in all of this, but it's your call
    if (array.Length != bytes.Length) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)     
        if (array[i] != bytes[i]) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Note that it would be quite nice to make it generic, but that would certainly cost a bit of performance as the comparison couldn't be inlined:

```
public static bool ArrayEquals<T>(this T[] first, T[] second)
{
    // Reference equality and nullity checks for safety and efficiency
    if (first == second)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (first == null || second == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (first.Length != second.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }        
    EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!comparer.Equals(first[i], second[i]))
        {
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your first, non-generic method also check for reference equality and nullity?

Comment: @Tommy: I wanted to leave the first version as close to the original as possible, but provide a fuller solution with more changes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to null check before doing the equality comparison? Or are you just doing this assuming that two null arrays are considered equal?

Answer (score 0):

I did this for the same purpose:

```
static class Global
{
    public static bool ArraysAreEqual(Array arr1, Array arr2)
    {
        if (arr1.Length != arr2.Length)
            return false;

        System.Collections.IEnumerator e1 = arr1.GetEnumerator();
        System.Collections.IEnumerator e2 = arr2.GetEnumerator();

        while(e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
        {
            if(!e1.Current.Equals(e2.Current))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

but notice that the .Equals() may even return false on reference-types when they are equal (I did not the test, but you can try with StringBuilder ). In my particular case I have only simple value-types

Comment: Unless u use a really backwords .NET version, I don't understand why you bother your self after having this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054459/i-wanna-have-an-extension-method-equals-between-2-byte-arrays/3106129#3106129

Comment: yes, because i am limited on the version of the .Net framework